# Understanding where cursor position of a file is stored and modified

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I have trouble understanding who and how is the cursor  position retained when writing or reading files using streams.

I have the following situation:

```
-Get a `stream`
-Write said `stream` to file
-Create a new stream and read said file
-This stream position is at end
```

Why is the newly created stream's position at end ?

```
class Program
    {
        public static async Task WriteAsync(Stream inboundStream,string path)
        {
            using FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            await inboundStream.CopyToAsync(fstream);

        }
        public static async Task<Stream> ReadAsync(string path)
        {
            MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream();
            using FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            await fstream.CopyToAsync(memstream);
            return memstream;
        }
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string path = "hello.txt";
            using (MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hello hey")))
            {
                await WriteAsync(memstream, path);
            }
            using Stream readStream = await ReadAsync(path); //why is the position of this guy at the end ?
        }
    }
```

I do not understand , when i write to a file , does the position of the cursor gets embedded in it or where is the cursor position stored?If there is no such position somehow stored then a new `Stream` that reads the resource should start from the begining.

Comment: There are no cursors in streams. When you write to the end, the position is the end of the stream. When you read to the end, the position is at the end of the stream, bacause that's what you did - you read to the end of the stream

Answer (score 2):

After reading from one stream and writing to another, the other stream is at its end because you just wrote it to the end.

Specifically this line:

```
await fstream.CopyToAsync(memstream);
```

`memstream` will now be at the end because it just had the other stream written to it.

You need to use `Seek` to start over. Right after the above line:

```
memstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: rather than duplicate your answer, I will edit yours. feel free to revert me if you feel I am over editing your answer.

Comment: I am using different `FIleStream`s for reading to file and writing as you can see ! I know i have to use `Seek` , if i would be using the same `FileStream` for reading and writing.That is not my case !

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian how is this not the case? When you write to a stream, the position points to the stream's end. If you read a stream to its end, the position is the stream's end. No matter the stream, if you want to go back to the start you need Seek.

Comment: But i am writing to a file using `FileStream` 1 lets call it `fs1`. And  i will be reading from the file using `fs2`.When you say `stream's end` which end are we talking  about ? `Fs1` is no longer used when i am reading the file.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian sorry didn't notice these comments sooner. It's `memstream` that is at the end, not the file streams. `fstream.CopyToAsync` leaves `memstream` at the end (which makes sense since if you were to write more to it, it should keep writing at the end.) In order to read `memstream` from the beginning, you need to "rewind" it first.